# What's the order of channel using YouTube Data API V3 `onBehalfOfContentOwner`

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?
  part=snippet,statistics,topicDetails,contentDetails&
  onBehalfOfContentOwner=XXX&
  managedByMe=true&
  maxResults=50&
  access_token=XXX
```

I wonder what is the order? And how to get the newly added channel?

Comment: Are you asking "what is the order of the channels returned by this query"?  And you want to know how to retrieve the most recent one?

Comment: Are you running this query as part of a script?  What language are you using?  Have you written any code yet?  If yes, are you able to post your code?  I can answer this question for you but I need some more info.